# How to solve the problem when buildings are extruded without roof?

Tags: arcscene, 3d-analyst, model

[image]

I tried to extrude buildings in ArcScene with Extrusion function in Layer Properties. But most of the buildings seem like only their walls are extruded. Instead of solid blocks, they appear like no roof and ground.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the printscreen? Are you sure that your buildings are polygons? http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_extrusion_as_3D_symbology

Comment: I've posted a screenshot to the original question. As you can see, most of the buildings are like only walls, only few of them are extruded as solid boxes. I have checked that they are polygons with Z values. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are all your houses polygons or are some of them line features?  If they are all polygons, have you checked the validity of the geometry?

Comment: Yes they are all polygons. How can I check the validity of the geometry? if they are not valid geometry, is there any way to repair them?

Comment: Thanks Sylvester Sneekly. It was the problem of geometry. I used Repair Geometry tool and now they are just pure solid blocks.